# Conversion from JSP to Thymeleaf

Tags: spring-boot, jsp, thymeleaf

I have a problem converting the following code from JSP to Thymeleaf. Can somebody help me please? Thank you!

```
 <c:forEach var="item" items="${category.products}">
    <c:out value="${item.name}" />
    </c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **th:each** and **th:block** if you don't want to create additional span tags.

```
<th:block th:each="item : ${category.products}" th:text="${item.name}">product</th:block>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use an HTML tag to let Thymeleaf do the th:each loop. If this is not part of a div or table, etc you can use the following code that does the loop in a  tag.

```
<span th:each="item : ${category.products}" th:text="${item.name}">empty product</span>
```

It will produce an output similar to:

```
<span>item 1</span>
<span>item 2</span>
<span>item 3</span>
```

Comment: This would produce HTML tags in the output.   The provided JSP block would not produce tags.

Comment: You are also missing the call to `name()`